# using external files and libraries while globally declaring type definitions flowtype

Tags: flowtype

So, I'm trying to declare a global $ListOf type that looks like this:

decls/immutable.js

`import {List} from 'immutable'`

`declare type $ListOf<X> = List<X>`

.flowconfig

`[libs]`

`decls/`

but when I check flowtype of $ListOf I get undefined. Is there anyway to use external libraries while creating global types? This would be really really useful if there was